# Terraform apply fails during GitHub Actions step

Tags: github-actions, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to deploy a simple budget on a subscription in Azure. Using GitHub Actions for CI/CD with OIDC authentication via a service principal.

However, the following error is outputted on the `terraform apply` step after the schematic of the planned infrastructure to be deployed is shown:

```
 Error: checking for presence of existing resource group: resources.GroupsClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: {"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\"\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\r\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>\r\n<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" Content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\"></HEAD>\r\n<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>\r\n<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n" '\x00' '\x00'} error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
│ 
│   with azurerm_resource_group.rg,
│   on main.tf line 25, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg":
│   25: resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
```

The codeblock deploying infrastructure is `main.tf`:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.80.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    key              = "budget.tfstate"
    use_oidc         = true
    use_azuread_auth = true
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = true
  features {
    resource_group {
      prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = true
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "budget-rg"
  location = var.rg_location
  tags     = local.common_tags
}
```

What I've done:

1. Ensured the resource group: `azurerm_resource_group` is created before being referenced by other resources.
2. Ensured there aren't any errors in the config files.
3. Authenticating to Azure is working via OIDC. Exemplified by the `az login` step in my YAML files output:

   ```
   Run azure/login@v1
   Running Azure CLI Login.
   /usr/bin/az cloud set -n azurecloud
   Done setting cloud: "azurecloud"
   Federated token details:
    issuer - https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com
    subject claim - repo:ZimCanIT/zimcanit-az-cloud-resume:ref:refs/heads/main
   Attempting Azure CLI login by using OIDC...
   Subscription is set successfully.
   Azure CLI login succeeds by using OIDC.
   ```

This is the file used to trigger the run:

```yaml
name: Push

# trigger pipeline if there is a push targeting the main branch within the az-infra/ subfolder
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'az-infra/budget**'

env:
  TF_LOG: DEBUG

permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
jobs: 
  deploy-infra:
    name: 'Deploy terraform infrastructure'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults: 
      run:
        shell: bash
        working-directory: 'az-infra/budget' # keep working tfm files in budget directory
    steps:
    # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    # Install the latest version of Terraform CLI 
    - name: Setup Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
      
    # Log into Azure with OIDC integration
    - name: 'Az CLI login'
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
        tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
        subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}

    # Run az commands to confirm sub access
    - name: 'Run az commands'
      run: |
        az account show
        az group list

    # Run Terraform init
    - name: Terraform Init
      id: init
      env:
        STORAGE_ACCOUNT: ${{ secrets.STORAGE_ACCOUNT }}
        CONTAINER_NAME: ${{ secrets.CONTAINER_NAME }}
        RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME: ${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }}
        ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
        ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
        ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
      run: terraform init -backend-config="storage_account_name=$STORAGE_ACCOUNT" -backend-config="container_name=$CONTAINER_NAME" -backend-config="resource_group_name=$RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME"

    # Run a Terraform apply
    - name: Terraform apply
      id: apply
      env:
        ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
        ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
        ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
      run: terraform apply -auto-approve
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Set the ghactions yaml file in debug mode, read the output and noticed the invalid URL request referenced the subscription id. Re-inputting the subscrition id as a gh actions secret resolved the error. This was noted by the below error:

```
2024-01-02T13:18:05.525Z [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.85.0_x5: AzureRM Response for https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/***%0A/resourcegroups/budget-rg?api-version=2020-06-01: 
HTTP/2.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 324
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Date: Tue, 02 Jan 2024 13:18:05 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```